# Can I add my own internal link in windows save/open dialog window?

Tags: windows

In windows 7 I am constantly saving things from the web and it really suck to have to navigate to my c drive then webserver folder then htdocs then project name then folder everytime I need to open or save a file there.  Windows open and save dialog box has option to quick jump to drives and things like my documents, my photos, music.   Is it possible to make my own quick jump link inside of these dialog windows?

Comment: Nice picture ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but this is very useful and I think some users may not know about it.  I went to start menu -> accessories -> windows explorer and it brought me to Libraries window, I right click and click on "New Library" then create a name for the new library, in my case " Web Server" then I right click it's icon and go to properties, there you can add any folder's you want to show up in this library.  This also makes this library show up in the open dialog window.

Very awsome windows 7 feature!!!

Answer (score 4):

can be done without libraries: just drag anything into the 'Favorites' folder on the left

Answer (score 3):

1. Run the Registry Editor
2. Navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32
   ```

   If `comdlg32` doesn't exist, you can create it. (right click *Policies* and select *New* > *Key*)
3. Create a new subkey called `Placesbar` under:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32
   ```

   (Right click *comdlg32* and select *New* > *Key* then enter *Placesbar* for the name.)
4. Go to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\Placesbar
   ```

   Create a String value named `Place0`. Give `Place0` a value of the top folder that you want to appear on the Open dialog box.
5. Create another String value named `Place1`. Give it a value of the second folder that you want to appear on the Open dialog box.
6. Close the Registry Editor. The changes that you have made will take effect and the specified folders will be added to the Open Dialog Box.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new library (Downloads say) then that should appear in the first section.