# Can I add a "place" to the Open... dialog in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add custom location is Save As dialog box?](https://superuser.com/questions/137741/how-to-add-custom-location-is-save-as-dialog-box)

There's an existing question for [Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/96195/can-i-add-my-own-internal-link-in-windows-save-open-dialog-window).

Is it possible to add new "places" to the Open/Save dialogs in Windows XP?

It's possible under Mac OS X (10.6 is what I'm running), and apparently in Windows 7. How about XP?

Comment: @Sathya - looks pretty similar, but @stijn has a different answer than TweakUI :)

Comment: I believe tweakUI does the same, but nevertheless, I was just pointing that there is a similar question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify to taste, save as .reg file, run it:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\PlacesBar]
"Place0"=dword:00000000
"Place1"=dword:00000011
"Place2"="d:\\projects"
"Place3"="d:\\downloads"  
"Place4"="c:\\"
```

first one is 'My Computer', second one 'My Documents'.
Google PlacesBar for more.

btw, this still has it's use in Windows 7 since not all applications use the new file dialog.